# How to save value of check boxes in android?

Tags: android, listview

I am using this code and now its working fine

ProcessList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
      {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 

            {

      AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(location.this);


      adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+ProcessList.getItemAtPosition(position));

      adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);

      adb.show();


            }
  });
```

Comment: @Dennis list items which user has checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getSelectedItem();` it return the Editable and if you need the string use `getSelectedItem().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would help you

(1) for list  set

```
mylistView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

mylistView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

(2) define list item as

```
<CheckedTextView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:background="@drawable/txt_view_bg"

/>
```

This is same as "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice" except "android:background="@drawable/txt_view_bg"

(3) you can define drawable txt_view_bg.xml as

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected"
  android:state_checked="true" />  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/not_selected" />
```

Note:- The preferred way to handle multiple choice is to track choices your-self with on click item click, rather than depending on its state in list.**USe this code , in the textview you can get to know which checkbox is check**